# tags below video tag not visible

Tags: html, html5-video

I am learning html5 and I write this simple snippet of code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>test video</title>
</head>
<body>
    <video src="movie.webm" controls/>
    <h1>this is a header below the video</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

The video is shown fine on the screen but the problem is that I am not able to view the `<h1>` tag below the video. I have tested in Opera and Firefox. Do you have any idea what I am missing here?

Comment: *Do you have any idea what I am missing here?*: http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to explicitly close the `<video>` tag:

```
<body>
    <video src="movie.webm" controls></video>
    <h1>this is a header below the video</h1>
</body>
```

Here's [an example](http://jsfiddle.net/6uGkF/). Notice how the first header is displayed, and the second is not.

And just for completeness, here's what [the spec has to say](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/#the-video-element):

> **Tag omission in text/html**:
>       Neither tag is omissible.

Comment: It works, thank you. But why the closing with `/>` is not valid in this case? Aren't those tags equivalent: `<video src=""></video>` and `<video src="" />`?

Comment: @niculare - No, that only applies to XHTML, not HTML5. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3558119/are-self-closing-tags-valid-in-html5) for full details.

Comment: Thank you very much for the prompt answer.